# Redshift PIVOT multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift, transpose

I have the following dataframe in Redshift, where every account has 6 months worth of data for multiple columns. In this example, I'm only showing one account with two columns `purch` and `bal`:

[image]

I know how to `pivot` for a single column, where it would be something like:

```
pivot(sum(purch) for mth in ('1' as purch_1, '2' as purch_2 ...))
```

but I'd like to blow out **multiple** columns wide with one row per account like this:

[image]

From what I've read online, the `pivot` function cannot process more than one column to make wide but maybe I haven't expanded my search enough.

Any idea how to do this efficiently for multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be through a combination of CASE statements and aggregate functions.
For example, to pivot the data for two columns purch and bal for six months. Assuming the mth column holds integer values from 1 to 6 representing the month and account is the account identifier.

```
SELECT
    account,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 1 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 1 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 2 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 2 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 3 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 3 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 4 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 4 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 5 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 5 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 6 THEN purch ELSE 0 END) AS purch_6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mth = 6 THEN bal ELSE 0 END) AS bal_6
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY
    account;
```

Comment: Thanks! Not the prettiest but it'll work just fine. I'm able to use SAS to loop over terms and months to create+copy+paste my SQL strings rather than typing all this out so no biggie.